# PowerShell get detailed event information from WmiEvent (System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher)

Tags: windows, powershell, events, event-handling, wmi

I want to get event delails like the event type and drive letter from a Windows Powershell event.

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange -Action {
param($event)
$eventType = $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType # don't work
write-host $eventType
}
while (1-eq1) {} # don't exit program
```

This is what i want to achieve. It works on a Windows computer, but because of performance problems it don't work on a Windows tablet:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
do {
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
write-host $eventType
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) # Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Comment: What is calling this and passing in an argument for the `$event` param?

Comment: The $event param is submitted by the WmiEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that multiple params are submitted:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange -Action {
param($event, $sourceEventArgs)
$eventType= $sourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
write-host $eventType
}
while (1-eq1) {} # don't exit program
```